# Deque using custom class cannot push_back

Tags: c++, deque

I am getting the following error when attempting to push_back a new custom object:

```
prog7.cpp:66: error: no matching function for call to 
    ‘std::deque<Job, std::allocator<Job>     >::push_back(Job*)’
    /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_deque.h:1201: note: candidates 
    are: void std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) 
    [with _Tp = Job, _Alloc = std::allocator<Job>]
```

Relevant code is here:

```
deque<Job> jobs;
jobs.push_back(new Job());
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, you're using `new`. You shouldn't use `new` in C++. It rarely does what you think, and it's never elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say this:

```
jobs.push_back(Job());         // copy from a default-initialized object
```

Or:

```
jobs.emplace_back();           // direct-initialize a new object
```

Comment: Thank you! Say I want to pop_front and assign that to a new Job. How is that done? I've tried Job newJob = Job(jobs.pop_front()); or Job newJob = jobs.pop_front(); but neither of these work

Comment: @netorious: popping *removes* an item. You can say `jobs.front()` to *access* the first item, and `push_front`/`emplace_front` to insert a new item at the front.